How much should the 5' adapter and i7 sequence differ?
In a multiome (RNA and ATAC) project I'm working on we chanced upon a strange situation. We're not sure if it poses a problem or not and would like to know if and where I can look it up if necessary.
Below is the sequence of our construct:
i7 index           GACGAGAT
                   ||||||||
5’-CAAGCAGAAGACGGCATACGAGAT[i7]GTGACTGGAGTTCAGACGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCT
           5' adapter       i7        TruSeq Index 

One of our i7 indices (top sequence) is almost perfectly similar to the end 5' adapter directly neighboring said index. Only the first position (G <-> T) differs between the two.
We get a very low number of reads within this project and we thought this might be one of the causes for that.
Can this situation pose a problem during sequencing? Has anyone encountered such a problem before?
Is it something one should avoid?

I am wondering if it would make more sense to ask this on our sister site, [biology.se], since this is really more about the biochemistry of sequencing than about the in silico analysis of the results. It's borderline though and there will be more people with NGS experience here than there, so up to you. If you don't get an answer after a while, consider deleting this and asking there.
